# List box not working on HTML form linked to my mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have three list boxes on my HTML form,AUTHOR,GENRE  and YEAR.These are linked to a sql database called Authors and a table called books.The idea is to click on one or all of the List boxes,the choice is then placed in variables then into a customised sql statement which extracts the data from the mysql DB and places the result in a table.The result only partly works.If I click one item from each box,then it reponds fine For Example EG Ken Davies(choice in author list) Adventure(choice in genre list) and 2007(choice in year list) Then this works fine.Also if I just click on an authors name,this works fine,or if I just click on genre,this works fine.However when I click on any of the years in the year list box,I dont get anything,despite the years working if I combine them into all three(authors,genre and year).Has anyone any suggestions please Many thanks.

```
      <html>
 <head>
 <title>My Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <br>
 <form name="myform" action="dropdown2.php" method="POST">

 <select name="author" size="4">
 <option value="ken davies">ken davies</option>
 <option value= "arthur smith">arthur smith</option>
 <option value="gill rafferty">gill rafferty</option><br />
 <option value="molly brown">molly brown</option><br />
 <option value="gilbert riley">gilbert riley</option><br />
 <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "go">

 <select name="genre" size="4">
 <option value="adventure">adventure</option>
 <option value="biography">biography</option>
 <option value="crime">crime</option><br />
 <option value="romance">romance</option>
 <option value="2007">thriller</option>

 <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "go">
 <select name="year" size="4">
 <option value="2002">2002</option>
 <option value="2003">2003</option>
 <option value="2004">2004</option>
 <option value="2005">2005</option>
 <option value="2006">2006</option>
 <option value="2007">2007</option> 
 <option value="2008">2008</option>

 <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "go">

 <?php


 $bird = ( ! empty($_POST['author'])) ? $_POST['author'] : null;
 $cat  = ( ! empty($_POST['genre']))  ? $_POST['genre']  : null;
 $mouse  = ( ! empty($_POST['year']))  ? $_POST['year']  : null;

 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
If (!$con){
     die("Can not Connect with database" .  mysql_error());
 }
  Mysql_select_db("authors",$con);
      if(isset($_POST['author'])&&isset($_POST['genre'])&&isset($_POST['year']))
 {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE author = '$bird' AND genre = '$cat'  AND year = '$mouse' ";
unset($_POST['cat']);
unset($_POST['bird']);
unset($_POST['mouse']);
    }


 elseif(!isset($_POST['author']))
 {
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE genre = '$cat' ";
      unset($_POST['genre']);   
 }

 elseif(!isset($_POST['genre']))
 {
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE author = '$bird'";
     unset($_POST['author']);
 }

 elseif(!isset($_POST['year']))     
     {
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE year = '$mouse'";
     unset($_POST['author']);
     unset($_POST['genre']);
     unset($_POST['year']);


 $myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);

 echo"<table border=1>

 <tr>
 <th>id</th>
 <th>author</th>
 <th>title</th>
 <th>publisher</th>
 <th>year</th>
 <th>genre</th>
 <th>sold</th>
 </tr>";


 while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>" . $record['id'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $record['author'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $record['title'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $record['publisher'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $record['year'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $record['genre'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $record['sold'] . "</td>";

     echo "<tr />";
 }
 echo "</table>";



 mysql_close($con);



 ?>



 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Where does the `<select` tag end?

Answer (score 1):

add mysql_error() for each query you have used and apart review your Html code it seems to be not pretty.

Comment: Hi Hitesh,thanks for the reply.I did what you suggested it brings up an"unexpected end of file error"

Comment: @moonshadow  dude unexpected end of file is syntax error where you might have forgot to close the braces or php tag review your code you will definitely find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

considering your database table name is books and its fields are title, author, genre, year and etc.

```
<?php

//database connection code here

?>

<form action="aaa.php" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Author</td>
            <td>
                <select name="author">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                    <?php
                        //gets all the name of the author in the database
                        $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT distinct author from books ORDER by author");
                        while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
                        {                               
                                echo "<option>".$row21['author']."</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Genre</td>
            <td>
                <select name="genre">
                <option value="adventure">adventure</option>
                <option value="biography">biography</option>
                <option value="crime">crime</option><br />
                <option value="romance">romance</option>
                <option value="2007">thriller</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Year</td>
            <td>
                <select name="year">
                <option value="2002">2002</option>
                <option value="2003">2003</option>
                <option value="2004">2004</option>
                <option value="2005">2005</option>
                <option value="2006">2006</option>
                <option value="2007">2007</option> 
                <option value="2008">2008</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="submit" value="submit"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<?
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{


    echo "<table>";
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from books where author='".$_POST['author']."' and genre='".$_POST['genre']."' and year='".$_POST['year']."' ");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                echo "<tr>":
                    echo "<td>".$row['title']."</td>":
                    echo "<td>".$row['author']."</td>":
                    echo "<td>".$row['genre']."</td>":
                    echo "<td>".$row['year']."</td>":
                echo "</tr>":
            }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Nolly,many thanks for the reply.I am just getting three Listboxes up,with only the authors names populated,and also what looks like a  text box with the word select in.Alos the "table" code is not compiling.Any suggestions much appreciated